# Database structure for 2000 data per second and real-time shown?

Tags: sql-server, database, real-time

I am working on a monitoring project based on Web. There are nearly 50 sensors with the sample frequency 50Hz. All the raw data of sensor must be stored into the database. That means that nearly 2500 data per second will be deal and 200 million per day. And the data must be saved for at least three years. My job is making a webserver to show the real-time and historical sensor data through the database. The time-delay displaying is allowed.

1. Which database should we choose for this application?  SQL server or Oracle?  Is it possible for these databases to stand so huge I/O transactions per second?
2. How to design the database structure for real-time data and historical data? My opinions are that there are two databases, one store real-time data, another store historical data. First the coming data was stored in real-time database, and at the some time(eg. 23:59:59 every day ), I write a sql transaction to transfer the real-time data to the historical database. So for the real-time displaying, it read the real-time database.  And for historical data shown, it read historical database. Is it feasible? And how to determine the time to transfer the data? I think on day is too long for some huge data.
3. How to store the time information? It comes a data per 20 million seconds. For one data + one time information, the database will expand so huge. For that the datetime type of sql server 2008 take 8 byte space. For 50 data+ one time information , the volume of database will reduce ,but for the data shown , it will cost time to get ervery data from the 50 data. How to balance the database size and the efficient of data reading?

Comment: if your database can handle it than you still have a problem with the client you are writing. It also needs to be able to send that many inserts to the database / second. I would let the client fill up arrays and let another thread read the arrays and do the inserts in the database. This way your client can receive and process all sensor data faster than it can insert them into the database

Comment: this question is primarily opinion-based. I can't say you, what is better MS SQL Server or Oracle. You problem can be solved with both of them. and in different ways

Comment: This question should be closed as both vague and opinion-based. Although you could compare licensing costs for both databases. You should also check the available *features* for each database because they may already do what you ask - SQL Server 2016 Enterprise has in-memory tables with updatable columnstore indexes that automatically spill to disk if memory isn't enough. Besides, what do you mean huge data? Both databases support compression. In fact, the top TPC-H benchmark for unclustered (ie single machine) databases is a 30TB SQL Server 2016 machine by Lenovo

Comment: To explain: an in-memory table with a columnstore means that you get real-time inserts *and* an index that supports analytics on top of it. Although, a cloud-based event processing solution in front of the database would be cheaper and far more scaleable. You can add more processing power to an Azure Event Hub right from the UI. You can't do the same with a database

Comment: @Backs thanks for your reply. the database is the oracle 11g,which is bought by my boss. how to solve the real time display and history data query?

Comment: @GuidoG thanks  for your reply.  My application is web server, and the client connected with the web server through the http protocol. how the client handled the sensor data without the database? And the progmmer of getting data is  written by other company.